# xcodebuild error DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE while executing single command line test, but the all test case command works fine

Tags: xctest, xcodebuild, xcuitest

I can execute my project using XCUItest with following command:

```
xcodebuild test -workspace Maple.xcworkspace -scheme Maple -configuration Debug -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 
8,OS=11.4'
```

This command works fine, and all my test cases run.

I want to execute a single .swift file. so I used the following command:

```
xcodebuild test -workspace Maple.xcworkspace -scheme Maple -configuration Debug -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=11.4' -only-testing:/Users/amit.jathar/Maple/MapleUITests/DashboardTests.swift
```

The above command throws following error:

User defaults from command line:
        IDETestRunOnlyIdentifiers = (
        "Maple/MapleUITests/DashboardTests"
    )

--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Unable to open project file '/Users/amit.jathar/sdm-maple-ios/MaplePlayground.playground' in workspace 'Maple.xcworkspace'.

2018-07-12 17:44:55.000 xcodebuild[13879:5394085] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-14161/IDEFoundation/Execution/Schemes/IDETestSchemeAction.m:272

Details:  (anyTestRunSpecification) should not be nil.
Object:   
Method:   -testOperationWithSchemeOperationParameters:testManager:withBuildOperation:buildParameters:schemeCommand:actionRecord:testRunSpecifications:deviceAvailableChecker:outError:actionCallbackBlock:
Thread:   {number = 1, name = main}
Hints:

Backtrace:
  0   -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   -[IDETestSchemeAction testOperationWithSchemeOperationParameters:testManager:withBuildOperation:buildParameters:schemeCommand:actionRecord:testRunSpecifications:deviceAvailableChecker:outError:actionCallbackBlock:] (in IDEFoundation)
  4   -[IDEScheme _executionOperationForSchemeOperationParameters:build:onlyBuild:buildParameters:title:buildLog:dontActuallyRunCommands:restorePersistedBuildResults:deviceAvailableChecker:error:actionCallbackBlock:] (in IDEFoundation)
  5   -[IDEScheme schemeOperationForSchemeOperationParameters:buildLog:overridingProperties:overridingBuildConfiguration:dontActuallyRunCommands:restorePersistedBuildResults:deviceAvailableChecker:error:completionBlock:] (in IDEFoundation)
  6   -[IDEScheme schemeOperationForSchemeOperationParameters:buildLog:overridingProperties:overridingBuildConfiguration:dontActuallyRunCommands:restorePersistedBuildResults:error:completionBlock:] (in IDEFoundation)
  7   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool _buildWithTimingSection:] (in Xcode3Core)
  8   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
  9   main (in xcodebuild)
 10   start (in libdyld.dylib)
Abort trap: 6

Comment: I've have figured it out! The parameter : -only-testing:/Users/amit.jathar/Maple/MapleUITests/DashboardTests.swift should not be  used with absolute path of the test suite file, instead it should be the relative path inside the scheme, like: -only-testing:MapleUITests/DashboardTests